# How to find specific JavaScript code in parsed HTML using cheerio with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, cheerio

I want to find a single JavaScript code/keyword like `zopim` or `v2.zopim.com` in whole script with using cheerio on NodeJS. I wrote a script that grabs all links from a single web site but the script need to opens all these grabbed links and search for "zopim" keyword in JavaScript codes. I looked cheerio's [repository](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) and it's [issues](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues) but no luck. I'm wondering could anyone help me to figure out this situation? 
This is a part of my code that where I open links and search in source code for a keyword. I can post all of it if it's necessary.

```
function () {
    //console.log(totalUrls);
    console.log("Crawling is done.")
    if (page == 16) {
        console.log("Anaylzing web sites...");
        async.whilst(
            function () {
                return checkedUrl < totalUrls.length;
            },
            function (urlCallback) {
                var currentUrl = totalUrls[checkedUrl]
                request(currentUrl, function (err, res, body) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + err);
                    }
                    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                    $('.headerContent').each(function () {
                        var title = $(this).find('a').text();
                        console.log(currentUrl + title);// if the current web site has a '.headerContent' class print it.
                        // I want to print only if web site source code includes "zopim" keyword in JavaScript code
                    });
                    checkedUrl++;
                    urlCallback();
                });
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:contains` selector to find scripts which contain keyword `'zopim'` in text and then count found script elements:

```
const scriptsWithKeywordCount = $('script:contains("zopim")').length;
if (scriptsWithKeywordCount > 0) {
    // webpage contains keyword in javascript code
}
```

Comment: Something looks like wrong in your code. Your code solved my problem but your code find how many `zopim` keyword in a script and the script contains 4-5 zopim keyword and when I print `scriptsWithKeywordCount` with `console.log` it says there is one `zopim` keyword. I don't understand why but worked for me thank you so much!

Comment: @tpbafk it shows amount of `script` elements that contain keyword (not amount of keyword in script element). So if you have 1 script with 5 keywords - result should be 1, that's fine